# Can't use soap service in magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, soap

Can't use soap service
When I test soap with this script:

```
try {
$opts = array(
            'http'=>array(
                'header' => 'Authorization: Bearer token'
            )
        );
$wsdlUrl = 'https://host/soap/default?wsdl=1&services=testModule1AllSoapAndRestV1';
$serviceArgs = array("id"=>1);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, ['version' => SOAP_1_2, 'stream_context' => $context]);

$soapResponse = $soapClient->testModule1AllSoapAndRestV1Item($serviceArgs); 
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```

I get this error:

```
SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://host/soap/default?wsdl=1&services=testModule1AllSoapAndRestV1' : failed to load external entity "https://host/soap/default?wsdl=1&services=testModule1AllSoapAndRestV1" in /var/www/vhosts/host/httpdocs/scripts/soaptest.php:12 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/host/httpdocs/scripts/soaptest.php(12): SoapClient->SoapClient('https://host...', Array) #1 {main}
```

Comment: please check with https://gist.github.com/rafaelstz/ecab668b80fece4d9acdb9c5358b3173

Comment: Magento providing REST service why your using SOAP?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this code, hope its work for you...

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require('vendor/zendframework/zend-server/src/Client.php');
require('vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client.php');
require('vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client/Common.php');

$wsdlurl = 'https://host/index.php/soap/default?wsdl&services=salesOrderRepositoryV1';

$token = 'dx2x7pl5mxq9hp8jr8efcl5crv2pk699';


$opts = ['http' => ['header' => "Authorization: Bearer ".$token]];
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
//$arguments =
$serviceArgs = array('searchCriteria'=> 
        array('filterGroups' => 
            array ('filters' =>
                array('field' =>'increment_id',
                      'value' => '000000002' , 
                      'condition_type' => 'eq')
                )
         )
);
$soapClient = new \Zend\Soap\Client($wsdlurl);
$soapClient->setSoapVersion(SOAP_1_2);
$soapClient->setStreamContext($context);
$result = $soapClient->salesOrderRepositoryV1GetList($serviceArgs);//array('searchCriteria' => $serviceArgs));
//$result = $soapClient->customerCustomerRepositoryV1GetById(array('customerId' => 1));
/*'search_criteria'=> 
        array('filter_groups' => 
            array ('filters' =>
                array('field' =>'firstname',
                      'value' => 'Veronica' , 
                      'condition_type' => 'eq')
                )
         )
);*/
echo "<pre>"; print_r($result); 
?>
```

Comment: same problem here

Comment: i update code, create one custom file in root and add token which we generating from admin. and test it.

Comment: it doesn't work